# Ejabberd clustering over SSL?

Tags: ssl, xmpp, ejabberd, openfire

Our web and mobile application suite is used by some government agencies requiring strong security. We're providing XMPP-based chat. We used Openfire as XMPP server, but it turned out Openfire clustering (provided by Hazelcast plugin) does not allow Openfire nodes to communicate over SSL. We're not allowed to use node-to-node communications without SSL.

So, we're currently looking at Ejabberd XMPP server as a (more scalable) alternative to Openfire.  But it looks like Ejabberd cluster nodes also communicate without SSL.  Is it possible to set up Ejabberd cluster with nodes using SSL to talk to each other?

Comment: Have you tried Tigase? It is also Java based XMPP Server, offers clustering with SSL communication between cluster nodes.

Comment: I found this link but didn't try anything yet: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/erlang-distribution-over-tls.html

Comment: Could you point me to a place in documentation explaining how to set Tigase cluster nodes to use SSL?

Answer (score 3):

There is two ways to enable clustering over TLS with ejabberd:

1. You can set Erlang distribution over TLS: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/ssl_distribution.html
2. You can use VPN to protect your cluster.

Typically, the second solution is best for performance, as you offload the SSL processing from your cluster to a lower level layer. Clustering in ejabberd is not intended to be set over the internet, as you need low latency between your node for optimal operation.